# "error: class expected" for two-dimensional array nested 'for' loop

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, error-handling, nested-loops

```
public class TwoDmArrayPractice {

  public TwoDmArrayPractice() {
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    double[][] data1 = new int[4][5];

    for(int i=0; i<data1.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j< data1[].length; j++)
        {
            data1[i][j] = j;
        }
    }       
  }
}
```

Hey all, I'm messing around with two-dimensional arrays using 'for' loops to fill the array
I understand how this nested for loop is working I just keep getting an error on the line containing the second 'for' loop arguments. I have searched everywhere for a similar issue but to no avail.

Comment: oops didnt change double to int in constructor. still gives same error

Comment: you should mention the programming language you are using in the tags

Comment: Don't proof in comments; you can edit your own post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your second for loop:

```
for(int j=0; j< data1[i].length; j++)
```